# Excel to calculate capacity levels

Tags: excel

I have a table in excel setup as followed:

```
DATE | TIME | PERSON IDENTIFIER | ARRIVAL OR LEAVING
01/01/15 | 13:00 | AB1234 | A
01/01/15 | 13:01 | AC1234 | A
01/01/15 | 13:03 | AD1234 | A
01/01/15 | 13:05 | AE1234 | A
01/01/15 | 13:09 | AF1234 | A
01/01/15 | 13:10 | AB1234 | L
01/01/15 | 13:15 | AG1234 | A
01/01/15 | 13:13 | AC1234 | L
```

The table shows when people arrive and leave a medical ward. The ward holds 36 patients and I'm wanting to get an idea of how close it is to capacity (it's normally always full). The ward is open 24/7 and has patients arriving 24/7 but I'd like to show the time it is at the certain capacities.

For example if we inputted 24 hours of data

```
36 patients (0 empty beds) - 22hr 15min
35 patients (1 empty bed)  - 01hr 30min
34 patients (2 empty beds) - 00hr 15min
```

I'm thinking we just need a count for every time some arrives and a negative count when they leave but I can't figure out how to extract the time from that.

Comment: Is the data always in sequential order, or (your last two entries) can it be out of temporal order?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your methods would be count how many in the department, however I'm trying to see how long we are maximum capacity, how long we are not at maximum capacity (unless I've misunderstood you).

Comment: It can be put in time order. I think you've helped me figure it out - much appreciated! I'll give that a whirl at work tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be pretty ugly (NB using your columns from above):

- order the entries sequentially
- you can keep a running tally in column E of patients on hand currently with `E1 = 36`(or whatever starting value you have) and `=IF(D2="A",E1+1,E1-1)`.
- Get the time elapsed since the previous entry with `=(B3-B2)` and put that in column F
- Count the chunks where you had less than a full house with  `=SUMIF(F:F, "<36")`